# iOS App with introduced Share Extension works only on devices having never installed the app before

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, share-extension

We have an iOS product having run fine for a long time with several updates.

In the latest release a Share Extension was introduced (requiring an additional Provisioning Profile). The extension is for photo sharing directly from the Photos App and it then utilizes the logged in user in the main app.

The App is in the App Store and was submitted without errors.

But, the Share Extension only works when the App is installed on a new device which has never had it installed before. On a device which has had it installed previously, the Share Extension does not work. Deleting the App and reinstalling does not solve the problem.

Any ideas?